# Making Minecraft Mod. Compile error

Tags: java, lwjgl, minecraft

I am making some key-binds for my speed-hack.
I have part of the key-binds done.
This is the error I get
I think it is caused by putting the boolean in the wrong place.

== MCP v4.4 ==

```
> Recompiling client...
javac -g -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -classpath "lib/:lib/*:jars/bin/minecraft.jar:jars/bin/jinput.jar:jars/bin/lwjgl.jar:jars/bin/lwjgl_util.jar" -sourcepath src/minecraft -d bin/minecraft src/minecraft/net/minecraft/isom/*.java src/minecraft/net/minecraft/client/*.java src/minecraft/net/minecraft/src/*.java  conf/patches/*.java failed.
Return code : 1
```

== ERRORS FOUND ==

```
src/minecraft/net/minecraft/src/GuiIngame.java:48: illegal start of expression
public boolean checkKey(int i)
^

src/minecraft/net/minecraft/src/GuiIngame.java:48: ';' expected
public boolean checkKey(int i)
^

src/minecraft/net/minecraft/src/GuiIngame.java:48: ';' expected
public boolean checkKey(int i)
^
```

CODE

```
{
    public boolean checkKey(int i)  

    if(mc.currentScreen != null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(i) != keyStates[i])
    {
        return keyStates[i] = !keyStates[i];
    } else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

EDIT
NEW PROBLEM

CODE

Stack overflows formatting is funny so using pasteie
http://pastie.org/2741100

Comment: You error is listed as being on line 48, so you aren't giving us all the code necessary to aid in solving the problem.

Comment: You want the entile .java file?

Comment: Well, like I said, you error is on line 48, chances are it's not with the method syntax. More code relevant to the error would be nice, at least for me.

Comment: Updated pastie with file

Comment: your checkKey() method is inside another method...

Comment: @jtl999 So, we've given you some basic advice on solving your original problem and after reviewing your latest past of code and errors I see ultimately what your problem is and I'm going to point you towards [Getting Started with Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html)

Comment: @jtl999 And a bit of advice as to your current problem, you've written a method within a method.

Comment: Good luck on your hacked client :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
{
    public boolean checkKey(int i)  

    if(mc.currentScreen != null)
```

to:

```
public boolean checkKey(int i)  
{

    if(mc.currentScreen != null)
```

Assuming the rest of your file has proper syntax.

Comment: Good fixed it up a little but new problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have your `{` placed before the `public boolean checkKey(int i)`. It should be placed just after it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now, the method before `checkKey` (`renderGameOverlay`) has no closing bracket, which is most likely what is throwing those errors. Indenting your code properly will help solve those problems.

EDIT*

By "help solve those problems" I mean that it will be easier to notice they're missing.

Comment: I will put then in a new pastie now